# How does ADO.Net know which version of the SQL Native Client to use if you have both SQL 2005 and 2008 in your environment?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

How does ADO.Net know which version of the SQL Native Client to use if you have both SQL 2005 and 2008 in your environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic services, they're backward compatible so you don't even have to worry about it: if 2008 native client is installed, it should connect to 2005 or 2008 databases transparently.

The only problem you run into is some parts such as DTS or SQL-DMO, which apparently require a separate download for backwards compatibility:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en

Installing those will mean that you won't have to worry about the existence of the 2005 native client on the system.

Does that help?